# How to use RegEx to replace a character in multiple text strings

Tags: regex, replace, textwrangler

My text is as below:

```
• heading 1\n» text_string: text_string\n» text_string: text_string\n• heading 2\n» text_string: text_string\n» text_string: text_string
```

I want to change `\n» text_string:` into `\n» text_string\n -` so the text should be displayed in my app as:

```
• heading 1
  » text_string
    - text_string
  » text_string
    - text_string
• heading 2
  » text_string
    - text_string
...
```

How can I use RegEx (Grep) to find `\n» text_string:` and replace it by `\n» text_string\n -`?

(I'm using TextWrangler).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change this:

`• heading 1
» text_string: text_string
» text_string: text_string
• heading 2
» text_string: text_string
» text_string: text_string`

to this:

`• heading 1
» text_string
    - text_string
» text_string
    - text_string
• heading 2
» text_string
    - text_string
» text_string
    - text_string`

I rather that you do something like this

```
text.replace(/:\stext_string(\n|$)/ig,"\n\t- text_string\n");
```

that is a normal regexp in javascript, I hope that help you somehow

Comment: I still don get used to the text formatting, but I hope that you understand

Comment: I'm not sure he actually has "text_string" in his file that many times, although it wasn't made clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By 'text_string' I mean any word or series of words. Unfortunately, I'm only used to TextWragler or Notepad ++, so don't know what to do with your prompt.

Comment: hmmm I see, I thought that you was using javascript or something, my bad

Comment: Provided: - @mechdeveloper did correctly (re)format both of your original and expected text, - you really want just to replace `:` with `\n - ` -- and - there are no additional colons in your text_strings: How is the result of a TextWrangler search for `:` and replace with `\n - ` different from what you are looking for?